# ORA-39171 ORA-01659 impdp

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to restore my Oracle backup version 11.2.0.1 to another server version 11.2.0.4.

When I run the impdp, the ORA-39171 and ORA-01659 erros are shown.

`impdp hosp/xxxx file=HOSP3001.DMP logfile=loghosp3001.dmp version=latest schemas=HOSP`

In the .dmp file I have the following TABLESPACES and DATAFILES:

```
DATAFILE                                          | TABLESPACE
```

---

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/dbs/HOSP      | HOSP
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/dbs/HOSPDATA  | HOSPDATA
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/dbs/HOSPDATA2 | HOSPDATA
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/dbs/HOSPDATA3 | HOSPDATA
```

I have created in the new server the follwing TABLESPACES and DATAFILES.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE HOSP DATAFILE 'HOSP' SIZE 1024M ;
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'HOSP' RESIZE 1024M ;
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'HOSP' AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED ;

CREATE TABLESPACE HOSPDATA DATAFILE 'HOSPDATA' SIZE 1024M ;
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'HOSPDATA' RESIZE 1024M ;
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'HOSPDATA' AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED ;
```

In this new scenario I intend to keep just one DATAFILE for the TABLESPACE "HOSPDATA".

Comment: Which tablespace is the ORA-01659 referring to? It's generally helpful to include the whole error stack from running the command as part of the question.

Comment: I don't know which one tablespace, there are two in the .dmp file as I mentioned. I know the error appears when the impdp is creating the indexes. The console does not specify which index is being compiled.

Comment: The ORA-01659 should tell you which tablespace it can't allocate minextents for. I'm not sure why you aren't including the console output in the question so we can see the errors you are getting.

Comment: Well, I haven't included the console output because it does not show which tablespace has the error and any details about what's going on. At least it should have a logfile with more details, but I don't know if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your alert.log, most probably you will find the answer there. It looks like you do not have free space in the tablespace.

Comment: I don't think so. Cause my tablespace has unlimited maxsize and there is lot of free space in my hard disk. Where can I find the alert.log?

Comment: "unlimited maxsize" - does not mean that your file is really unlimited unless you use "big file tablespace". By default Oracle use "small file tablespace" this means that you file can grow up to 4M of DB_BLOCKS (usually this is 16G or 32G).

Comment: Alert log file is in background_dump_dest folder. In order to find background_dump_dest parameter value do this:

Comment: Well... if you can not find your alert log file that means that your knowledge about oracle are poorer that I thought. I will try to explain -  alert log file is located in background_dump_dest folder. In order to find background_dump_dest parameter value do this: in SQLPlus type "show parameter background_dump_dest" this will return a path to the file. Now ho to that path and look for file which name starts with "alert*.log", that is your "alert log file"

Comment: Sergiu Velescu, you are the man!
It workes now. I changed the my data create datafile as you suggested:

CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE HOSP DATAFILE 'HOSP' SIZE 1024M ;
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'HOSP' RESIZE 1024M ;
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'HOSP' AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED ;


CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE HOSPDATA DATAFILE 'HOSPDATA' SIZE 1024M ;
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'HOSPDATA' RESIZE 1024M ;
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'HOSPDATA' AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED ;

Answer (score 0):

ORA- 39171:is usually caused by a non expandable tablespace running out of space leading to stall of the Data Pump job. Adding datafiles to the tablespace running out of space will usually solve the problem.

ORA-01659: Explains the actual cause of  ORA- 39171. In this specific case, oracle failed to find sufficient contiguous space to allocate MINEXTENTS for the segment being created. Again, the solution will still be adding a datafile to that tablespace.

If you still want to import the data into a single DATAFILE, oracle provides a remapping utility as follows:
         REMAP_DATAFILE=source_datafile:target_datafile

Answer (score 0):

you can use impdp with option "**transform=segment_attributes:n**"